# Custom List in Fragment wont work

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-drawer

So im new in Android programming I'm trying to make a custom ListView. I follow a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAIB4fTm2BA) but i cant get it work on a fragment.

```
public class DriverFragment extends Fragment implements GeneralFragment   {

ListView listView;
public DriverFragment() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driver, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.driverList);
    DriverAdapter driverAdapter = new DriverAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.driver_listview);
    listView.setAdapter(driverAdapter);
    Driver a = new Driver("John Smith","Johnsmith@example.com","123");

    driverAdapter.add(a);

    return view;
}
```

Driver Adapter :

```
public class DriverAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

public DriverAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


static  class Holder{
    TextView NAME;
    TextView EMAIL;
    TextView PHONE;
}
public void add(Driver driver) {
    list.add(driver);
    super.add(driver);

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.list.get(position);
}

public  int getCount(){
    return  this.list.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.driver_listview, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.NAME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.driverName);
        holder.EMAIL = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.driverMail);
        holder.PHONE = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.driverPhone);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder  = (Holder) row.getTag();

    }
    Driver driver = (Driver)getItem(position);
    holder.NAME.setText(driver.getName());
    holder.EMAIL.setText(driver.getMail());
    holder.PHONE.setText(driver.getPhone());

    return  row;

}
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="DriverName"
    android:id="@+id/driverName"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="DriverMail"
    android:id="@+id/driverMail"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="DriverPhone"
    android:id="@+id/driverPhone"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last answer didn't seem to help, I quickly put something together.

I would strongly advise reading up more on this topics since Lists and Adapters are an integral part of Android development and having an understanding of how it works is really helpful.

```
public class Driver {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Driver a = new Driver();
        a.setName("Name");
        a.setEmail("Email");
        a.setPhone("Phone");

        ArrayList<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<>();
        drivers.add(a);

        DriverAdapter driverAdapter = new DriverAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.driver_listview, drivers);
        listView.setAdapter(driverAdapter);

        return view;

    }
```

Adapter

```
public class DriverAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Driver> {


    public DriverAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Driver> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        Holder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.driver_listview, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.driverName);
            holder.email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.driverMail);
            holder.phone = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.driverPhone);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder  = (Holder) row.getTag();

        }
        Driver driver = getItem(position);
        holder.name.setText(driver.getName());
        holder.email.setText(driver.getEmail());
        holder.phone.setText(driver.getPhone());

        return  row;
    }

    public class Holder {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView email;
        protected TextView phone;
    }
}
```

Adapter XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driverName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="DriverName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driverMail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="DriverMail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driverPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="DriverPhone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If this doesn't help you, there is a problem with your fragment showing on the device. As I have tested this myself and it displays correctly on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

first of all if you should really check out some good tutorial like

Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Assuming everything is okay with your Fragment and it´s visible, lets focus on your Adapter. Since your DriverAdapter has it´s own ArrayList of data there is no point in calling super.add() in it´s add() method. You just call notifyDataSetChanged() to let the Adapter know that it should refresh the content on the UI. Try something like this..

```
public class DriverAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
ArrayList<Driver> data = new ArrayList();

public void add(Driver driver) {
    data.add(driver);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addAll(List<Driver> drivers) {
    data.addAll(drivers);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Driver getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_driver_row, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverName);
        holder.email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverMail);
        holder.phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverPhone);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    Driver driver = getItem(position);
    holder.name.setText(driver.getName());
    holder.email.setText(driver.getEmail());
    holder.phone.setText(driver.getPhone());
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    return convertView;
}

static class Holder {
    TextView name;
    TextView email;
    TextView phone;
}
```

}

Comment: I tried adding the notifyDataSetChanged() method but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting your adapter to the ListView before you add anything to it, which is fine but you must call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in order to update the list with the new data.

Although, I would suggest changing how you create your adapter. Everytime I have used any sort of adapter, I create my list of data before and pass it in through the constructor. Then set it to my listview. So like:

```
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_driver, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.driverList);

    Driver a = new Driver("John Smith","Johnsmith@example.com","123");
    ArrayList<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList();
    drivers.add(a);

    DriverAdapter driverAdapter = new DriverAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.driver_listview, drivers);
    listView.setAdapter(driverAdapter);
```

This is a only rough example of what I would do, I would advise you to read up on some examples from Google around this. Also read up on RecyclerViews instead of ListViews if possible.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/

Comment: I tried adding the notifyDataSetChanged() method and also i added the adapter after adding the object but it still does not show .